# In yii how to include php file and access its inputs

Tags: yii

In yii i want to create simple password.php file and want to give just one text field for enetering email id and submit button. This file does not belongs to any model. In actionpassword method i want to access this email id for further processing. So where to create this file and where to write actionpassword method.
I am very new to yii framework. So please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Yii - use Yii. You need action and view.
In your controller:

```
public function actionPassword() {
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
       $email = $_POST['email'];
       //process email....
       //....
    }
    $this->render('_emailForm');
}
```

View './views/yuorControllerId/_emailForm.php'

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'email-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    ));
echo CHtml::textField('email');
echo CHtml::submitButton('Send');
$this->endWidget();
```

Comment: Thanx sir for reply. I had created new _emailForm.php file in views->user1 folder with code as   <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'email-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    ));
echo CHtml::textField('email');
echo CHtml::submitButton('Send');$this->endWidget();                                       and also created actionPassword method in controller. But when i am trying to run this email page by inserting r=User1/_email in addressbar its giving an error as "The system is unable to find the requested action "_email". Plz help me

Comment: your action is called actionPassword (and your controller name - User1, I guess), so to get this page type:
/index.php?r=User1/password

Comment: In actionPassword method i want to compare this user's inserted email id in databse wheather it exists in table. If yes then server will send security question to him else will give him error msg. So how to implement this. Can someone help me